# How to get a default column to change to an empty set in an INT type row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the image of my database

[image: pic of database]

These are the queries/commands that I have tried in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE mismatch_response ALTER COLUMN user_id SET DEFAULT '';

ALTER TABLE mismatch_response MODIFY user_id SET DEFAULT '';
```

This is the error message that I'm getting:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'response'
```

I'm thinking it's because the column is an INT column but I have seen and done this before but since I've upgraded to mysql version 14.14 distr 5.7, I'm getting this error message.

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting this error message and how I can get the results that I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's as you expect. It has to be an INT (or NULL), it can't be, for example, an empty string.

Comment: @Jon Stirling Thanks but the program won't work how I want it to without that so what can I use instead of the empty string that would have the same effect?

Comment: Leave the default as NULL?

Comment: That really depends upon what on earth you are trying to do

Comment: Ok. I'll try leaving it as null again and check the program. @RiggsFolly I'm trying to fill the table with response data. I dont know if that explains it.

Comment: So I set it the column back to '0' instead of an empty string and it works like that but my question is will this affect how my database works in anyway?

Comment: So a response_ID can exist without a user?

Comment: @xQbert No the response_id column remains set as NULL.

Comment: So then why set a value or empty string or anything at all?  When a record is attempted to be added to this table, you want it to fail if the code didn't provide a user_ID.  Why would you ever want a default?  so if you leave default 0 and a programmer doesn't provide a user_ID now you have bad data in the system... seems like a mistake to me.  I'd leave it not null no default.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am following a book so I just wanted to know how to get it to the books specifications but I will remember that for future reference. Thanks alot.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to alter column `user_id`, but the error you are getting is for column `response`.  So I would look for a problem in the definition of `response`.

Comment: @Enwired. I was trying to do the same thing to all the columns but I used that error message and that code because I was drawing reference from that one. They are all saying the same thing. I just set it back to '0' and it worked so I guest its ok like that. I just wanted to know how to get it to the books specifications but it seems thats a bad idea to leave the DEFAULT column as an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

First your `user_id` doesnt allow `NULL`, so if you want store `NULL` you need to change that.

Second if default is `NULL` you dont need to specify `DEFAULT`.

Last if you want a default value need to be same type of the field column, in this case you can use `0` or `-1`  or another value `-999`, but you cant use empty string `''`